# difference between specific rows

Tags: sql, teradata

I would like to approximate how long users stay on an external link. Therefore I want to see the difference between when they click on the external link and when their next click is on my website.

My database looks as follows (important columns stated):

- clsfd_session_id (identifier for each session, I would to have the time spend on external link per session).
- clsfd_event_action: what click is performed on the site (e.g. external link click).
- clsfd_total_event: number of clicks performed of the event.
- clsfd_event_categ: to which category the event action belongs to.
- hit_start_time_num: when the action is performed (in seconds).

So far I've identified all sessions which have > 1 clsfd_event_action. However, I have a hard time filtering out that the session MUST have an external link click, plus other clsfd_event_action(s).

```
select clsfd_session_id, count(*)
from table
group by 1
having clsfd_session_id> 1
```

What I want are all the sessions which have an external link click (= R2SExternalBegin), and after that another row (so that the sessions does not end but the visitor returns to my site).

In the picture below you can see **1 session, including 1 external link click (R2SExternalBegin), followed by 1/more rows (thus the session does not end at the external link)**. The difference between the numbers in the last column in the red rectangle is the time spent on the external link. 
[image]

**The output I want:**
All sessions which have 1/more R2SExternalBegin clsfd_event_action, FOLLOWED by another row (which means that the user comes back to the site). Note that there are around 50 different clsfd_event_actions.

Comment: `the session MUST have an external link click, plus other action type(s)` ... this is confusing, and possibly a contradiction.  Please show us clear sample table data, and the expected output.

Comment: Is it clear enough now? The example has an ExternLink action_type PLUS other action type(s). So the output needs to contain an ExternalLink action_type PLUS any other action_type(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select clsfd_session_id, count(*)
from table
group by 1
having
   -- there was a 'R2SExternalBegin'
   min(case when clsfd_event_action  = 'R2SExternalBegin' then hit_start_time_num end)
   -- and there was different action later
 < max(case when clsfd_event_action <> 'R2SExternalBegin' then hit_start_time_num end)
```

Comment: Smart thinking, appreciate it a lot!